# Duplicate fcm push notification in react native android backgroundhandler

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed react native application with `rnfirebase` and `notifee` for sending the push notification. foreground is working properly, message is displayed only once. but the background notification is displaying twice like one is from `messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler` and another one is android's default push notification. First message is from default push notification and next one is from firebase messaging. So how do I remove android's default push notification. I'm also checked that first default notification is not using the firebase messaging and notifee. It's comes from outside of react native like android's native push notification

[image: See this image]

Comment: No. I do not find a solution to this issue. This issue is caused by firebase messaging. because my expo app is also using the same firebase messaging like rnfirebase

Comment: i has the same issue

Comment: any update on this? i am facing same annoying issue.

Comment: just remove the notifee background message handler. that is only the way now. background handler is already pinned with your android project via gms services or firebase

Answer (score 4):

The notifications that you are seeing are most likely one from firebase and another from Notifee.
In my project I was handling the notifications that were coming from firebase via `firebase.messaging().onMessage` and inside this listener I was showing a local notification using Notifee so that the notification shows in the foreground.

```
async showNotificationInForeground(message: FirebaseMessagingTypes.RemoteMessage) {
    const { messageId, notification, data } = message
    const channelId = await Notifee.createChannel({
      id: messageId,
      name: 'Pressable Channel',
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    })

    await Notifee.displayNotification({
      title: notification?.title || '',
      body: notification?.body || '',
      data,
      android: {
        channelId,
        importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
        pressAction: {
          id: messageId,
        },
        smallIcon: 'ic_stat_name',
        localOnly: true,
      },
    })
  }
```

However what was happening was that I was calling this `showNotificationInForeground` method to show the local Notifee notification on both firebase's background and messaging listeners ie: `firebase.messaging().onMessage` and `firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler`

So what I ended up doing was only calling the `showNotificationInForeground` method in `onMessage` listener and not in `setBackgroundMessageHandler`, which resulted in showing the local notification in the foreground, and the firebase notification in the background.

If this is not the case for you, you are most likely registering an extra notification receiver inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file which is causing the duplication

Comment: I understood. but the background notification handler does not have the notifee or react native push notifications design aspects. if I stop the notifee background listener, I receive only a default background message in Android, which is really not from the firebase.

Comment: @KarthikeyanGanesan how did you solve this then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, where there were two notifications a) 1 from notifee (which I wanted to keep) b) from FCM (which I didnt want).
Sending a data only message from my custom server solved the issue. Below is a snippet of the serverside for sending data only message :

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Do other stuff like create an express server to listen and trigger sending message 
// Note dont forget to to initialize the app

await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
    tokens, // ['token_1', 'token_2', ...]
    {
      data: {
        owner: "Me",
        user: "My Friend",
      },
    },
    {
      // Required for background/quit data-only messages on iOS
      contentAvailable: true,
      // Required for background/quit data-only messages on Android
      priority: "high",
    }
  );
```

You can use other methods as well, just make sure that FCM doesnt include notification and is data only.