# FCM sending duplicate push notifications, but only sometimes

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using cloud functions to send push notifications to users (anywhere from 5-700 tokens) through the admin SDK. Here is my code:

```
const sendNotificationToTokens = async (title: string, body: string, tokens: string[], eventID?: string) => {
    if (tokens.length == 0) {
        functions.logger.log("FCM tokens empty")
        return
    }
    while (tokens.length) {
        const splitTokens = tokens.splice(0, 500) //Messaging can only send up to 500 devices in a single request

        let payload = {
            notification: {
                title: title,
                body: body,
            },
            android: {
                notification: {
                    sound: "default"
                }
            },
            apns: {
                payload: {
                    aps: {
                        sound: "default"
                    }
                }
            },
            data: {},
            tokens: splitTokens
        }

        if (eventID) {
            payload.data = {
                eventID: eventID
            }
        }

        admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload).then((response) => {
            functions.logger.log(`Successful send of notification to ${response.successCount} tokens with title: ${title}, message: ${body}. Failed to send to ${response.failureCount} tokens`)
            if (response.failureCount > 0) {
                response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
                    if (!resp.success) {
                        console.log(`Failed to send to token: ${splitTokens[idx]} with error: ${resp.error}`);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

However, it sends duplicate notifications (usually 1 and then another 30s later) about half of the time it runs. Cloud functions logs indicate that it's only sending the notification once, as it should, but it still sends two of the notification. I thought it might have been something with sending multiple multicasts at the same time, but I was able to replicate the issue when sending to only a few tokens (only able to replicate this once though). I am using react native firebase and the issue happens on both android and iOS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507734/duplicate-fcm-push-notification-in-react-native-android-backgroundhandler)? Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hmmm. It doesn't seem to be related to the issue in that post. Also, the issue is happening on both iOS and Android

Comment: Same here with topic based push. Did you sort it out?

Comment: Nope, still have not figured it out. Are you also using React Native for your app?